# How do I use a variable in Perl regex/replace?

Tags: regex, perl, variables, replace

Basically I'm trying to insert a line in a text file and I'm spawning a system command to execute "perl -pi.orig -e"

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
my $find='# Foo Bar'
my $replace="foo/bar/blah.txt\n# Foo'

my $file = './some_text_file.txt'

system("perl -pi.orig -e 's|$find|$replace|;' $file");
```

This works without the use of variables.

$file has the following text in it:

```
# Foo Bar is a comment
then/a/path/to/a/file.txt
```

Comment: It works fine for me (if I first correct the syntax errors, like missing/wrong quotes and missing semicolons). Please provide the input file you are using so we can try to reproduce

Answer (score 4):

Don't call Perl from Perl, do the work directly in the one process.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $find    = qr/# Foo/;
my $replace = "foo/bar/blah.txt\n# Foo";
my $file    = './some_text_file.txt';

open my $in, '<', $file or die $!;
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
    s/$find/$replace/;
    print {$out} $_;
}
close $out;
rename "$file.new", $file or die "Can't rename";
```

Or, if you need to keep the backup,

```
rename $file, "$file.backup" or warn "Can't create backup";
rename "$file.new", $file or die "Can't rename";
```

Comment: @PrashantKulkarni: What do you mean by "didn't work"? It works for me.

Comment: Sorry, I hit return too soon.
Here's my debugger output:

 <code> DB<109> x $find = qr/# Foo Bar/
    0  Regexp=REGEXP(0x5c56eb8)
    -> qr/(?^u:# Foo Bar)/
    DB<110> x $replace = "include foo/bar/blah.txt\n# Foo Bar"
    0  'include foo/bar/blah.txt
    # Foo Bar'
    DB<111> x open my $in, '<', $file or die $!
    0  1
    DB<112> x open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die $!
    0  1
    DB<113> x while (<$in>) {s/$find/$replace/;print {$out} $_;}
    0  ''
    DB<114> x close $out;
    0  ''
    DB<115> x rename "$matchingfile.new", $matchingfile or die $!;
    0  1 <code>

Comment: @PrashantKulkarni: You are running something different to what I posted. `$matchingfile` and `$file` are different variables. Note that my script is [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) compliant.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo here in my comment. It's the same in my code

Comment: The file doesn't get modified

Comment: Does your file contain `# Foo Bar`? You have `# Foo` in the OP.

Comment: $file has the following text in it:
````
    # Foo Bar Blah
    path/to/another/file.xml
````

Comment: Sorry for the spam, can't figure out how to get formatting in my comments

Comment: I created a file containing lines with numbers, I inserted `# Foo` in the middle. Running the script modified the file.

Comment: @PrashantKulkarni You can't. Comments are just for comments. All relevant information (including code blocks) should be part of the question.

Comment: Note that using `my` in the debugger doesn't work, as each statement is executed in its own scope.

Comment: Tried again in the debugger without using `my` . Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try without the debugger. Have you removed `my` from the `open` statements, too?

Comment: @choroba You were right, worked without the debugger. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a one-liner you'd like to use in a program, [use Deparse](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/05/use-bdeparse-to-see-what-perl-thinks-the-code-is/) to see what you need to do:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pi.orig -e 's|$find|$replace|;' file
BEGIN { $^I = ".orig"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    s/$find/$replace/;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

From there you can see what you need to do.

[choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485220/2766176) does the same thing without the special variable `$^I` that does the file handling.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a simple regular expression and replace it with anything we wish to:

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NEFgu9/1/)

#### Test

```
use strict;

my $str = 'foo/bar/blah.txt\\n# Foo';
my $regex = qr/#\sFoo/mp;
my $subst = 'With Anything You wish To Replace';

my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;

print $result\n";
```

Comment: Their code is trying to run that regex on each line of a file and change the file. The `system` runs an external command, and their command to run is a perl one-liner, `perl -pie'...' file`, which changes a file "in-place" (see [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html))